# What does the number after a machine learning model name mean?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, machine-learning-model

I'm not sure if this is off-topic, but I'm posting here anyway.

So I saw lots of machine learning models have like an ID after their names, for example, `resnet101`, `resnet152`, `densenet201` etc. What exactly do those numbers `101`, `152` and `201` mean? And how it's determined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Icrmorin said the naming conventions may vary but for the examples you gave, ResNet and DenseNet, the numbers in the name correspond to the number of layers:

---

**DenseNet**

Table 1 in the [Densenet paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.06993.pdf) provides an overview:

[image: DenseNet variants]

As you can see, for example, in the DenseNet-121 column this network has $1+6*2+1+12*2+1+24*2+1+16*2 + 1 = 121$ layers and that is where the name is derived from.

---

**ResNet**

The [ResNet paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf) provides a similar overview:
[image: ResNet variants]

Again, you can see how the names are derived: for example ResNet-18 has $1+2*2+2*2+2*2+2*2+1=18$ layers.

---

Note that in both papers only conv. and dense layers are counted but not the pooling layers.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it refers to a version (like windows 10), sometimes it refers to a size of the parameters, like the size of a layer, the number of parameters (like for GPT models), or the size of parameters in memory. They are just names so we can know what we are talking about. I don't think there is a general convention.

Answer (score 0):

For complement the answer of @Sammy,

The *number suffix* in the name of network means **the number of layers that have learnable parameters**, such as convolution layer, fully conneted layer,  in the network.

Hence number suffix does not counts the non-learnable layers, such pooling layer and activation layer, do not have any learnable parameters.